# Android Studio, problema con matriz [N] x [N]

Tags: android, matrices

Lamento molestar con la consulta, tengo 1 matriz datos, y un vector donde guardo las imágenes. La matriz la lleno yo mismo ingresando los datos, y no logro entender porque no funciona el código ya que le asigno un lugar distinto al que muestro a continuación:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
```

A continuación explico el código:

Clase Adaptador

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

private static LayoutInflater inflater= null;

Context contexto;
String [][] datos;
int [] datosImg;

public Adaptador(Context contexto, String[][] datos, int[] datosImg) {


    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.datos = datos;
    this.datosImg = datosImg;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)contexto.getSystemService(contexto.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}



@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, null);

    TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
    TextView descripcion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
    ImageView imagen= (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);

    titulo.setText(datos[i][0]);
    descripcion.setText(datos[i][1]);
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);

    return vista;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return datosImg.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

Actividad alimentos

```
public class alimentos extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lista;

String[] [] datos = {
        {"Manzana con helado de banana","Tarta de Manzanas", "Revuelto light de zapallitos y fideos","Albondigas light con semillas de Sesamo y avena", "Sorrentinos light con poquitos ingredientes"},
        {"Manzanas o peras, ralladura de limon, canela, edulcorante, agua, bananas" , "Manzanas peladas, huevos, aceite, leche, stevia o edulcorante liquido", "Zapallitos, cebolla mediana, aceite, fideos cocidos, ajo, perejil" ,"Carne picada especial, avena, huevo grande, semillas de sesamo, maizena, sal","Masa de empanadas, queso cremoso, albahaca"}
};

int [] datosImg= {R.drawable.comida1, R.drawable.comida2, R.drawable.comida3, R.drawable.comida4, R.drawable.comida5};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alimentos);
lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLista);

lista.setAdapter(new Adaptador(this,datos,datosImg));
}


}
```

logcat

```
12-06 11:55:04.024 29051-29051/com.example.juan.diabetapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.juan.diabetapp, PID: 29051
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
    at com.example.juan.diabetapp.Adaptador.getView(Adaptador.java:39)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2474)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1301)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1203)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19176)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6116)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6116)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6116)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6116)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6116)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2695)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19176)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2496)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1455)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1709)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1328)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6730)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:826)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:716)
```

Comment: Recuerda que no molestas con ninguna consulta, al contrarío ayudas a la comunidad para tener información que pueda ayudar a otro desarrollador, saludos..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se especifica aquí:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2

indica que estas tratando de obtener un elemento de tu array ubicado en el elemento con indice 2 (`index=2`) que en realidad no existe.

Recuerda que inicia desde 0 el conteo de indices, por lo tanto los indices serían 0,1,2 (en total 3 elementos) pero en realidad en tu array contienes únicamente 2 elementos (`length=2`)

**Específicamente el error ocurre en `getView()` de tu `Adapter` , la solución es especificar `datos.length` con cantidad de elementos a mostrar en tu Adapter.**

Recuerda que el método `getCount()` especifica la cantidad de elementos a mostrar a tu adapter, en este caso debe ser

`datos.length` y no `datosImg.length`

---

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, null);

    TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
    TextView descripcion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
    ImageView imagen= (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);

    titulo.setText(datos[i][0]);
    descripcion.setText(datos[i][1]);
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);

    return vista;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //return datosImg.length;
     return datos.length; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas obteniendo mal los datos en el Adaptador cambia esto:

```
titulo.setText(datos[i][0]);
descripcion.setText(datos[i][1]);
imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);
```

por esto:

```
titulo.setText(datos[0][i]);
descripcion.setText(datos[1][i]);
imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);
```

Comment: GRACIAS MUCHAS GRACIAS !!! ahora se ve re bien, pero no entro todo el texto, supongo que con un salto de linea se arreglaria, muchisimas gracias en serio.

Answer (score 0):

`getCount()` debe devolver la cantidad de items del `RecyclerView` y debe coincidir con la cantidad de items que tiene el array de `datos`.

El array de datos tiene dos datos (cada uno de ellos un array de string).

Pero en lugar de devolver la cantidad 2 que es la cantidad de datos que tenes, estás devolviendo la cantidad de imágenes que es mayor.

Cuando `getView()` trata de buscar el tercer datos (index 2) tira el out of bounds exception porque `datos` no tiene 3 elementos.

Debería devolver `datos.length`

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return datos.length;
}
```